# Moving files into new subdirectory, except for existing folders?

Tags: windows, bash, directory

A Redditor had written me a great script that allowed me to move all the files in a series of folders into a new subdirectory in all those folders called New. However, I also have pre-existing folders (namely just 1 called "Journals") that have had their files moved into a subdirectory called New, as well.

How would I modify the following script (on Windows) to not touch any folders within the folders, or perhaps not touch any folder called Journals?

For example, the current directory looks like:

```
Parent/Folder name/tons of files/
Parent/Folder name/Journals/tons of files
```

(folder name = random string of alphanumeric numbers in the thousands). Each folder has a ton of files, and a folder called Journals.

I would like:

```
Parent/randomstring folder/New/tons of files/
Parent/randomstring folder/Journals/tons of files
```

The code they wrote for me:

```
# Run from search root
cd "O:\..."
# Change this to taste
export NEWDIR=New

find . | egrep '(mp4$|jpg$|png$)' |
while read FILE
do

BASEDIR=$(dirname "$FILE")
mkdir "$BASEDIR/$NEWDIR" > /dev/null 2>&1
mv "$FILE" "$BASEDIR/$NEWDIR"

done
```

This code would do the following:

```
Parent/randomstring folder/New/tons of files/
Parent/randomstring folder/Journals/new/tons of files
```

Comment: So you just want to rename the subfolder into an arbitrary name/string?

Comment: No? I have a bunch of files loosely in thousands of folders. I want those files in a folder called New, but i also have a folder that already exists, called Journals, with its on set of corresponding files that I want untouched. This script creates a folder in each of the thousands of folders and puts the loose files that exist in those folders into the new folder that was created called New, but the problem is it also puts the files in Journals in a new subfolder called New, which is what I don't want.

Comment: So you need to do a pattern match, if the path/directory has `Journals` skip it, that's how I understood your question.

Comment: Yeah! that would be correct

Comment: After the `do` add `[[ $FILE = *Journals* ]] && continue` , that might be all that you're missing.

Comment: update: That doesn't seemed to have worked mhm

Comment: `[[ $FILE = *Journals*  && $FILE = *FooBar* && $FILE = *MoreQux* ]] && continue` although the `case` statement would work too `case $FILE in *Journals*|*FooBar*|*MoreQux*) continue;; esac`

Comment: I tried that case too and for some reason it doesn't work. Would it matter that inside Journal is more folders? The script still goes down all the folders inside Journals and puts the contents into a new folder called New

Comment: If folder/directory the match would be `*/Journals/*` now we have a warning that we already have too much convi here.

Comment: @Aedam : I would first move all the files **except** those in `Journals` (using `-prune Journals` as option to `find`), and then move the files in `Journals` (or maybe just `mv Parent/Foldername/Journals Parent/randomstringfolder`).

Comment: @Jetchisel tried that, same problem!

Comment: @user1934428 sorry i'm not understanding, the goal is to not touch journals and anything inside them at all.

Comment: @Aedem: Then leave them where they are; but in your question, you said that you want to end the `Journals` in a different directory (randomstringfolder).

Comment: @user1934428 Ransom string is just a placeholder for thousands of folders that have loose files inside. Inside all those Random string folders is a folder called Journals. I want the loose files to be put inside a new folder called New, but I want the files and folders inside Journals to be untouched. The script in the initial post puts the loose files inside a new folder called new, but also puts all the files inside Journals in  a new folder called New inside Journals.

Comment: @Jetchisel my dumbass accidentally wrote the wrong folder name (I had journal instead of journals) in my testing folder scheme. Your code works:

    [[ $FILE = *Journals* ]] && continue

Comment: @Aedam : But this is exactly what I said in the first part of the comment: Use `-prune` and this will leave this folder untouched. No need for some additional logic!

Comment: @Jetchisel

I tried [[ $FILE = *Journals* && $FILE = *FooBar* && $FILE = *MoreQux* ]] && continue but that didn't work. It not only didn't ignore the other folders, but it also started looking inside Journals, too. Do you know what could be up?

Comment: Put globs `*` around it `*Journals*` but that expands to anything that has a named `Journal` in it , since it is a path/directory you can add the slashes `*/Journals/*` same with the others because file names cannot have slashes in them, well at least on the file system that I have been using/tried.