# How to speed up this Bash mv script?

Tags: windows, bash, directory

A kind soul from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61534732/moving-files-into-new-subdirectory-except-for-existing-folders) wrote a script for me:

```
# Run from search root
cd "O:\folder"
# Change this to taste
export NEWDIR=Gallery

find . | egrep '(mp4$|jpg$|png$)' |
while read FILE
do
[[ $FILE = *Journal* ]] && continue

BASEDIR=$(dirname "$FILE")
echo Moving $FILE from $BASEDIR to $NEWDIR
mkdir "$BASEDIR/$NEWDIR" > /dev/null 2>&1
mv "$FILE" "$BASEDIR/$NEWDIR"

done
```

The problem is: I have millions of files (spread across about 16,000 folders) that to be ran through this, however, when I run this script it's processing slowly. In 6 hours only 224 folders were processed (about 10,000 images/video).

**Is there a way I can speed this up?**

Also: for:

```
[[ $FILE = *Journal* ]] && continue
```

How do I change this line to ignore multiple folders?

Comment: You could replace the childprocess of `dirname`by a parameter substitution, i.e. `BASEDIR=${FILE%/*}`. You could get rid of the `echo` and instead supply the `-v` option to `mv`. You can surpress unnecessary writes to stderr in your mkdir command (because you are creating the same directory over and over) by `passing the `-p` option to `mkdir`.

Comment: Plus, your `continue` line is wrong. It should be `[[ $FILE == *Journal* ]] && continue`, because you want to do wildcard matching here, not literal comparision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be surely faster if you had `find` do the filtering for you:

```sh
NEWDIR='Gallery'
find \
  . \
  -type f \
  -iregex '.*\.\(mp4\|jpg\|png\)$' \
  -not -iregex '.*Journal.*/.*' \
  -printf '%h\0%p\0' |
    xargs -0 -n2 sh -c 'echo mkdir -p -- "$2/$1"; echo mv -- "$3" "$2/$1/"' _ "$NEWDIR"
```

Remove the `echo` when you are satisfied by the output.

Alternative method with `-execdir`:

```sh
NEWDIR='Gallery'
find . \
  -type f \
  -iregex '.*\.\(mp4\|jpg\|png\)$' \
  -not -iregex '.*Journal.*/.*' \
  -execdir sh -c 'new_dir="$1"; shift; echo mkdir -p -- "$new_dir"; echo mv -- "$@" "$new_dir/"' _ "$NEWDIR" "{}" +
```

With `-execdir` the bash script is run `cd` from the same directory as all the files found in this directory. So the script is run once per directory.

Here is the shell script that is run with `-execdir`:

```sh
# The new directory name is passed as first argument.
new_dir="$1"

# Remove the first argument from the arguments array,
# so it contains only file names.
shift

# Create the new directory.
mkdir -p -- "$new_dir"

# Move all the files from the argument array,
# into the new directory.
mv -- "$@" "$new_dir/"
```

Comment: Which part of the code do I replace with that snippet? Just the "find . | egrep '(mp4$|jpg$|png$)' |" ?

Comment: Just ran this and it touches the content inside Journal folder

Comment: @Aedam Added handling of `NEWDIR` variable and fixed the exclusion of the `Journal` directory name.

Comment: That worked!! If I want to avoid multiple folders can I just copy/paste the "-a -not -iregex '.*Journal.*/.*' \" line twice?

Comment: @Aedam or adapt the Regex to match all the folder names to exclude.

Comment: @Aedam I added an even faster method with `find -execdir`